# 74141 BCD-to-decimal converter lighting wrong/multiple LEDs

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm having trouble with a 74141 IC while building a nixie clock. At the moment I'm testing it with 10 leds and a 4K7 resistor, expecting them to light up one at a time as per schematic: [NTE74141 Integrated Circuit TTL − BCD−to−Decimal Decoder/Driver 16−Lead DIP Type Package](https://datasheet.octopart.com/NTE74141-NTE-Electronics-datasheet-32009451.pdf)

Trouble is, both output 0 and 2 lights up no matter what input I set (by connecting ABCD input pins to 5V or ground). Is the IC corrupt or did I miss some detail?

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: Double-check that your IC is in correctly.  As drawn, pin 1 should be in the bottom left.  You'll get better answers if you post a schematic rather than a Fritzing diagram.

Comment: Can you please post a schematics? Also I don't  think your 4K7 resistor is doing anything.